# How to convert for results into a list-Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to put my results into a list.

**Here is my code:**

```
from ise import ERS
l = ise.get_endpoints(groupID=my_group_id)['response']
```

**Here is my output:**

```
[('AA:BB:CD', 'cvr5667'), ('AA:BB:CC', '8888')]
```

**Here is my desired output which is a list of just the first elements of inside the parentheses:**

```
['AA:BB:CD','AA:BB:CC']
```

I am new at python and working with lists/dicts so any suggestions would. All I am trying to do it put the first elements inside the parentheses in one list like i showed.

Comment: you can use a list comprehension `[item[0] for item in output]`

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension (as suggested in comments too):

```
lst_1 = [('AA:BB:CD', 'cvr5667'), ('AA:BB:CC', '8888')]

lst_result = [i[0] for i in lst_1]
```

Answer (score -1):

With something like this ?

```
result = [('AA:BB:CD', 'cvr5667'), ('AA:BB:CC', '8888')]
first_elements_to_list = [tmp[0] for tmp in result]
print(first_elements_to_list)
```

print:

```
['AA:BB:CD', 'AA:BB:CC']
```

Comment: This is duplicate of other posted answer.